# How to Cache Frames Faster in Movie Clip Editor?

Tags: video, tracking, cache, movie-clip-editor

I'm trying to track a fairly short (~30 second) video, however while playing through the video it takes FOREVER to cache in all the frames. So far, I have only got to about half way through the clip before the caching pretty much stops, and Blender begins "Not Responding". From here the screen freezes and I am forced to manually turn off the computer.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Increasing the [cache limit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/system.html#sequencer-clip-editor) may help, but I think it sounds more like you are running out of ram, monitor your memory usage as you try caching the video.

Comment: My cache limit is already 28000. Sure enough though, as I was caching the video, the computer's memory got to 100%, and that was when the computer freezed. Any ideas?

Comment: If those values are correct, each frame is about 40MB big. I would advise you to render a proxy sequence of the files. Jpg images will do for most tasks.

Comment: The cache size is in MB so you are saying it can use 28GB of ram and I doubt you have that. If your memory usage is at 100% then you are using all of the physical ram in your machine - How much is that? You want blender's cache limit to be less than the free memory that you have before starting to use it. How much free memory do you have before starting blender?

Comment: @sambler My computer has 6.95 GB installed RAM without Blender open. Would you recommend changing the cache limit to about 4 GB?

Comment: That would be a reasonable value.

Comment: @sambler I just tried 4 GB and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, I'll just split the video into two parts.

Thanks anyway.